# Error when selecting table with aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to return the SUM of the price of some products.

```
SELECT UserID, ProductName, Price, SUM(Price)
FROM Product
```

and the error is :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Artikal.RegistarskiBroj' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I even tried to group it by `UserID` and the error won't go away

Comment: Looks like sql-server error why is mysql tagged in this question?

Comment: All columns needs to be or in the GROUP BY or aggregated for it to be a valid GROUP BY... or you write an minimal GROUP BY delivered table or subquery and JOIN that results with your information again.

Comment: Can you please provide a desired output and if possible also the table structure?

Comment: I want to get the SUM price of all the products in the product table.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a pretty clear error message.  You need a `GROUP BY` for the query.  Presumably, this is the query you want:

```
select UserID, ProductName, SUM(Price)
from Product
group by UserID, ProductName;
```

`Price` is being aggregated.  It should not be aggregated and it should not be listed separately.

EDIT:

If you just want the sum of the price, leave out the other columns:

```
select SUM(Price)
from Product;
```

Comment: I want to list a price as price and sumprice as total price .that is why

Comment: Why is it that when i select just the SUM(Price) from Product i get the total amount , but when i add UserID and ProductName i get each of the products with it's current price instead of the Sum?

Comment: @NikolaAntonijevic . . . I think you need to study up a bit on the SQL language.